# mysql sorting name and numbers

Tags: mysql, sorting

the table looks something like this

```
ID    |    name
----------------
1     | season 1 episode 1
1     | season 1 episode 2
1     | season 1 episode 3
*     | *
*     | *
1     | season 1 episode 10
1     | season 2 episode 1
1     | season 2 episode 2
1     | season 2 episode 3
*     | *
*     | *
1     | season 2 episode 10
2     | season 1 episode 1
2     | season 1 episode 2
2     | season 1 episode 3
*     | *
*     | *
2     | season 1 episode 10
*     | *
```

but when trying to sort this with

```
SELECT * FROM `episodes` ORDER BY `ID`, `name` DESC
```

the table sorts 10, 11, 12 etc in the wrong order

Comment: you need to normalize your table...put `name` into 2 columns `season` and `episode`

Comment: ...and don't store the words 'episode', or 'season'

Comment: Why are you storing id and name in separate columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this result because it's sorting strings, not ints. So it examines each character separately. the 1 of the 10 is taken first, and since 1 is less than 2 it sorts it before 2, even when 2 occurs on its own. Only then does it move onto the 0. It has no idea you intended it to be a number. And this is only working at all because the rest of the string is always the same length. If you started to have season 10 etc, it would likely get even worse.

The solution is to separate your name field into two integer fields - "season" and "episode". Simply fill them with the relevant numbers. Often episodes have a separate descriptive title which you can hold in a string field, if you have it.

You can then do `ORDER BY season, episode` in your query to get them in the right order. If you want to display the text as seen in your current name field to the user, then you can do something like `SELECT "season" + CAST(season as CHAR(50)) + " episode " + CAST(episode as CHAR(50))` in your query.

Comment: I know that method i just, hoped for a better solution. well well what is a bit of extra work.

Comment: It's a bit of extra work but it'll give you more flexibility in the long run about how you use your data. Glad it helped you. Storing the words "season" and "episode" repeatedly was also kind of redundant, since they were purely for presentational use, and you were storing numbers as strings, which reduces your ability to search or compute them as numbers, as demonstrated by this issue. So actually it's an improvement to your data structure, rather than a chore :-)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `episodes` ORDER BY `ID`, CHAR_LENGTH(`name`)
```

Comment: IMO, suggestions to try something should be given in comments. And how should this correctly order `season 1 episode 1` and `season 1 episode 2`?